# JS/jquery updating numbers in HTML turns into NaN on mobile

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a made a little page for my fantasy football league:
http://www.legendary.no/gamecenter

It simply loads html from nfl.com, and updates the scores every 60 seconds. (I've set it to 6 seconds for testing purposes)

Works great on desktop, but on my iPhone, both in Safari and Chrome, when 6 seconds pass and it updates the numbers, they all turn into a NaN instead.

Anybody know what's wrong here, why it works fine in chrome and safari on desktop, but on mobile it doesn't?

Edit: This is the script from the page:

```js
       $("#hide").load("http://fantasy.nfl.com/league/1444853/team/1/gamecenter?week=14 #teamMatchupNav");
       window.setInterval(function() {
         for (i = 1; i < 11; i++) {
           newScore = parseInt($(".teamTotal.teamId-" + [i]).text(), 10);
           oldScore = parseInt($("span.team" + [i]).text(), 10);
           $('span.team' + [i]).text(newScore);
           if (newScore > oldScore) {
             $('li.team' + [i]).removeClass("up down none").addClass("up");
           } else if (newScore < oldScore) {
             $('li.team' + [i]).removeClass("up down none").addClass("down");
           } else {
             $('li.team' + [i]).removeClass("up down none").addClass("none");
           }
         }

         function sortEm(a, b) {
           return parseInt($('.teamscore', a).text()) < parseInt($('.teamscore', b).text()) ? 1 : -1;
         }
         $('.semi1').sort(sortEm).prependTo($('ul#Semi1'));
         $('.semi2').sort(sortEm).prependTo($('ul#Semi2'));
         $('.semi3').sort(sortEm).prependTo($('ul#Semi3'));
         $('.semi4').sort(sortEm).prependTo($('ul#Semi4'));
         $('.semi5').sort(sortEm).prependTo($('ul#Semi5'));
       }, 6000);
```

And a code example:

```html
<ul id="Semi1" class="matchup">
  <li class="semi1 team4">Thomas
    <em class="diff"></em>
    <span class="team4 teamscore">0</span>
  </li>

  <li class="semi1 team1">Jonas
    <em class="diff"></em>
    <span class="team1 teamscore">0</span>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: post relevent code plz...

Comment: NaN stands for not a number. If there is any type conversion in js, it throws NaN error. for exact help, plz post your code.

Comment: Added the script to the post.

Comment: I know what NaN is, I just can't figure out why it throws the error only on mobile.

Comment: Try to open this URL on mobile and see whether its loading or not. http://fantasy.nfl.com/league/1444853/team/1/gamecenter?week=14

Comment: ahhhh... That is obviously the issue, that nfl.com has a different mobile site.  Thanks, Mangesh.  Edit: Just changed the url to one that works on both, and it is now fixed. Thanks again